# What is the modern equivalent to netstat -peanut

Tags: networking, process-management, netstat

I heavily rely on viewing output of `netstat` as in

```
sudo netstat -peanut

Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          27575      1902/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          26977      1519/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          15340      537/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20953      925/nginx: master p 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8181            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25191      1236/haproxy        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        17893      716/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20941      921/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25193      1236/haproxy        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20954      925/nginx: master p 
tcp        0      0 172.18.0.1:44638        172.18.0.2:27017        TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 172.18.0.1:44774        172.18.0.2:27017        ESTABLISHED 0          31237      1528/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 172.18.0.1:39470        172.18.0.3:27017        ESTABLISHED 0          32005      1574/docker-proxy
```

here is another gem

```
netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1902/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1519/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      537/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      925/nginx: master p 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8181            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1236/haproxy        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      716/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      921/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1236/haproxy        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      925/nginx: master p 
tcp6       0      0 :::27017                :::*                    LISTEN      1594/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      1915/docker-proxy
```

however `netstat` is supposedly being replaced by tools like `ss`, etc ... does anyone know how to produce output similar to above the modern way ?

```
sudo ss -l -p -n   

sudo ss -tnlp
```

are my attempts yet not close enough to the lushness of `netstat` and the ss formatting is not human read friendly

debian/ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

First command:

```
ss -tap
```

Second command

```
ss -tlp
```